# pulley friction assumptions

Tags: friction

I have a dispute with this lecturer I have been given over the equation $T_2/T_1=e^{μθ}$. My opinion is that since it is derived from $T_2=T_1+\text{Friction}$, so the first equation is valid ONLY in situations where the speed rotates with constant speed, ie. When there is no acceleration in the wheel of the pulley. He finds my opinion strange, can you advise me please?

Comment: The [capstan equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation) applies when "the rope is on the verge of full sliding", i.e. zero rotational speed.

Comment: You have quoted the "capstan equation" which is usually used in static situations and $T_2$ is the maximum load that force $T_1$ can hold.  $\mu$ would then be the coefficient of static friction.  It sounds as though you are discussing a situation when there is slipping between the rope and the capstan?  If that is the case for what reason is there a problem if there is an acceleration?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation